# Node.js middleware redirect not working

Tags: node.js

Hi my url starts with /getSystemInfo 1st, checks if logged in, if has valid license. If no license, will redirect to askForLicense page, but this redirect is not working.

```
app.get('/getSystemInfo', isAuthenticated, hasLicense, function(req, res)
{
    logger.debug('querying iStar status');
    ...
}

var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next)
{
    if( req.isAuthenticated() ) {
        console.log("Very good, you are logged in ...");
        return next();
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, you are NOT logged in yet ...");
        res.send(401);
    }
}

var hasLicense = function(req, res, next)
{
    // queryLicense.py will return error is no license
    var getLicense = exec('queryLicense.py',
                     function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                         if (error !== null) {
                             console.log('License exec error: ' + error);
                             res.redirect('/askForLicense');
                         } else {
                             console.log("---- good, you have license ----\n");
                             return next();
                         }
                     }
    );
};

app.get('/askForLicense', function(req, res)
{
    console.log("---- Notice: need license ----");
    res.sendfile(path.resolve('../client/askForLicense.html'));
});
```

The console output is like this:

Very good, you are logged in ...

License exec error: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c getLicense.py

But i don't see the log in /askForLicense, why ?
Many thanks !

Comment: no need to return next, just do next()

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware functions are called in this order,

```
/getSystemInfo, isAuthenticated, hasLicense, /askForLicense
```

Since you are calling `exec("getLicenese.py")` inside the middleware, `hasLicense` and it throws error, the call doesn't reach the next middleware `/askForLicense`

Comment: How to fix this please ?

Comment: check why `getLicense.py` fails in the shell terminal. Possibly, the file may not have execute permissions. (or) you may need to pass `python` as the cmd to exec function and give the file name `getLicense.py` as an extra argument